# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VERSION_STRING'

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, osx-lion

I am working in Eclipse on Mac. I am using PyDev version 2.6.0.2012062818. I have a program that was running perfectly, but after I updated my Lion OS to Mountain Lion OS I have the following error while running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mihails/Projects/memsim/src/memsim/memsim.py", line 7, in <module>
     from simulation import SimulationHP
  File "/Users/Mihails/Projects/memsim/src/memsim/simulation.py", line 9, in <module>
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 95, in <module>
     new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
     globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wxagg.py", line 23, in <module>
     import backend_wx    # already uses wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py", line 63, in <module>
     backend_version = wx.VERSION_STRING
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VERSION_STRING'
```

I don't understand wx module at all. I don't have wx folder in site-packages. I have wxPython. wxPython init.py file :

```
# The "old" wxPython package

import warnings

warnings.warn(
    "The wxPython compatibility package is no longer automatically generated "
    "or actively maintained.  Please switch to the wx package as soon as possible.",
    DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)

# We need to be able to import from the wx package, but there is also
# a wxPython.wx module and that would normally be chosen first by
# import statements.  So instead we'll have a wxPython._wx module and
# then stuff it into sys.modules with a wxPython.wx alias so old
# programs will still work.

import _wx
import sys
sys.modules['wxPython.wx'] = _wx
wx = _wx
del sys

from wx import __version__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you update, some files have been replaced.

On Ubuntu 11.04 wx.VERSION_STRING, return string value.

Try reinstall WX, or append the 'VERSION_STRING', to WX main file.

Comment: Which one is the main wx file?

Comment: print wx.__path__. And in this file append 'VERSION_STRING' variable. In Linux main WX file is '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/' but file __version__.py. Maybe given for you source of this files?

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__' . I guess there is problem with the whole wx. By the way is wx the same as wxPython ?

Comment: Try test __path__ on other modules, we can understand, problem in Python or in WX.

Comment: I don't have wx folder. In wxPytnon init.py:

Comment: if you don`t have wx folder, you don`t have wx too. Install wx and your problem is get out

Comment: I can't find it. Google only shows wxPython. I tried easy_install, it says that it installs wx 1.0.0 and I have an egg file "wx-1.0.0-py2.7.egg" but no "wx" folder

Comment: When you install wx, in console print pathway where easy_install setup wxPython? If yes, move to this path and find __init__.py file and __verstion__.py file

Comment: I posted _init_.py in the original question. And I don't see version.py in wxPhyton folder.

Comment: Hmmm, in my __version __.py, I see in first line comment:
# This file was generated by setup.py...

Meybe try install without easy_install?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I reinstalled all the thing and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar problem just now. I am working on Winodws and MacOSX.

Today when I excute my python program that use matplotlib and wx, it just pops out that message.

I fixed by:
1. I uninstalled the wx through pip;
2. install wxpython;
3. update matplotlib from 1.2.0 to 1.2.1;

I guess the problem is the package `wx`I installed from pip is not wx at all and it override my wxpython import somehow.

Hope this information could give you some hint on your problem as well as others.